# Can't save user profiler image

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm working on Ruby script with Twitter API. I try to save profile image fetched but couldn't.

```
@image = subject.user.profile_image_url
=> #<Addressable::URI:xxxxxxxx URI:http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/xxxxxxxxxx/m_xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg>
```

I want to save only image URI. It's not concise.
How can I remove `#<Addressable::URI:xxxxxxxx >`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `path` method:

```
@image = subject.user.profile_image_url.path
```

Check more in [documenation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/2.2.4/Addressable/URI#path-instance_method)